# ReferenceError: Error #1008 Class is ambiguous

Tags: actionscript-3, symbols, linkage, ambiguous

I have a As3 file and I get a runtime error:

`ReferenceError: **Error #1008**: Tooltip is ambiguous; Found more than one matching binding.`

I have a class named `Tooltip` and also a symbol in library with linkage class: Tooltip and Base Class fvg.Tooltip (fvg is the name of the package).   Why I get this conflict?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! I had to import the **Tooltip class** in my Document class file.